# Pandas dataframe don't merge on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good evening,

I have a problem with my df

Here is df1

[image: ![enter image description here]

and df2

```
    Trimestre   level_0
0   "A1101" Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons"
1   "A1401" Maraîchers, jardiniers, viticulteurs"
2   "A1405" Maraîchers, jardiniers, viticulteurs"
3   "A1406" Marins, pêcheurs, aquaculteurs"
4   "N3101" Marins, pêcheurs, aquaculteurs"
... ... ...
123 "K1205" Professionnels de l'action sociale et de l'ori...
124 "K2104" Professionnels de l'action culturelle, sportiv...
125 "K2108" Enseignants"
126 "K2110" Formateurs"
127 "K2111" Formateurs"
```

I try to merge df1 with df2 on "Trimestre" column

```
df2.Trimestre = df2.Trimestre.astype(str)
df1.Trimestre = df1.Trimestre.astype(str)

df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Trimestre")
```

and nothing appear

```
Trimestre   level_0 2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020
```

Help me pls

EDIT: Here is the output of df.head().to_dict() to reproduce the error

df1

```
{'Trimestre': {0: 'A1101 ',
  1: 'A1201 ',
  2: 'A1202 ',
  3: 'A1203 ',
  4: 'A1204 '},
 '2010': {0: 2630, 1: 1380, 2: 4450, 3: 20330, 4: 130},
 '2011': {0: 2790, 1: 1500, 2: 3670, 3: 20040, 4: 90},
 '2012': {0: 2700, 1: 1320, 2: 4020, 3: 19140, 4: 130},
 '2013': {0: 2970, 1: 1690, 2: 3520, 3: 20500, 4: 140},
 '2014': {0: 2680, 1: 1980, 2: 2790, 3: 16900, 4: 150},
 '2015': {0: 2440, 1: 1780, 2: 2640, 3: 16310, 4: 170},
 '2016': {0: 3600, 1: 1980, 2: 2540, 3: 17680, 4: 90},
 '2017': {0: 2930, 1: 2470, 2: 2510, 3: 18520, 4: 130},
 '2018': {0: 2740, 1: 2010, 2: 2130, 3: 19280, 4: 150},
 '2019': {0: 1600.0, 1: 1760.0, 2: 1050.0, 3: 14260.0, 4: 80.0},
 '2020': {0: 11140, 1: 6490, 2: 14000, 3: 76580, 4: 510}}
```

df2

```
{'Trimestre': {0: 'A1101', 1: 'A1401', 2: 'A1405', 3: 'A1406', 4: 'N3101'},
 'level_0': {0: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons"',
  1: 'Maraîchers, jardiniers, viticulteurs"',
  2: 'Maraîchers, jardiniers, viticulteurs"',
  3: 'Marins, pêcheurs, aquaculteurs"',
  4: 'Marins, pêcheurs, aquaculteurs"'}}
```

Comment: Maybe the quotation is the problem. Try df2.Trimestre = df2.Trimestre.str.replace('"', '') before the merge.

Comment: Thanks @Wilian for the answer, i tried but didn't work....

Comment: Even when I do `df1.Trimestre.isin(df2.Trimestre)` I got False for every rows...

Comment: Please post the output of `df.head().to_dict()` for both dataframes so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RJ Adriaansen I have edited my post with the output

Comment: In `df1` the values in the `Trimestre` column have trailing whitespaces. If you fix that you get a non empty output

Comment: @Tranbi is right. This should fix it: `df1['Trimestre'] = df1['Trimestre'].str.strip()`

Comment: @Tranbi I don't how to thank you... It's been 3 hours now... thank you very much :)

Comment: By the way thank you @RJ Adriaansen for your help too